# best toolbox for simulating multiagent systems

Tags: netlogo, multi-agent

I want to simulate a multiagent system. Is netlogo good for that? Does it have good abilities for simulating all multiagent systems with any characteristics. 
Is netlogo good in graphic ? 
Can we do task sharing between agents with netlogo?
Can we do functional analysis with netlogo?

what other toolbox do you suggest?

Comment: what kind of simulation are you looking for?

Comment: I want to simulate a swarm behavior. I don't know which tools is better?  Netlogo , Jade or Repast. I want my agents can follow some rules for example they can minimize a cost function and they can obey some functions.

Answer (score 1):

Netlogo is good and easy and fast to implement. If you are an experienced Java programmer you might think of Mason too. I am using netlogo for social simulation, so far I did not feel that I need anything more than what Netlogo has, but I have performance problems which I might never faced with Mason.  It all depends on what do you need from each agent and what are your priorities. You can check this website to see the different models and their characteristics and different frameworks used for developing them :

http://www.openabm.org/

Comment: If you are new to netlogo , netlogo dictionary is the best place to start, you can also search netlogo video tutorials on youtube and you will find a series of tutorials which will get you started.

Comment: Can i write a path or cost function in netlogo that all of my agents try too Minimize that function? and how is netlogo in graphic?

Comment: By graphic I am not sure what you mean, but you can see the visual movement of agents in 2D and 3D and have variable monitors to check variable changes and plots as well, but honestly I am not sure what you mean by graphic. I believe you can minimize cost function in netlogo as well.

Comment: a path finding algorithm example : http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Astardemo